# Calculating Net Promoter Score for specific time period

Tags: mysql

I need to transform data, so it comes into my BI software pivoted. I found somewhere on internet the following query to calculate Net Promoter Score (NPS), however there's a problem - it calculates ALL the data and ignores WHERE statement, where I try to specify the year and month. It means, that it takes all the rows for all the years and outputs calculation for them.

```
SELECT NPS_Deployment_Type
     , CAST(((SUM(CASE WHEN NPSRating BETWEEN 9 AND 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 -
SUM(CASE WHEN NPSRating BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS signed) NPS
     , count(*) as 'SR'
  from g360_relationship_survey_extract 
 where year(Survey_Response_Created_Date) = '2017' 
  AND month(Survey_Response_Created_Date) >= '10' 
 GROUP 
    BY NPS_Deployment_Type
```

Note: Net Promoter System is customer experience survey, that asks a question with a rating ranging from 0 to 10 (inclusive). It is calculated as: 
((Number of people who replied 10 or 9)/all responses - (Number of people who replied 0-6)/all responses) * 100

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

First, use

```
 WHERE Survey_Response_Created_Date >= '2017-10-01'
   AND Survey_Response_Created_Date <  '2017-11-01'
```

to get all responses in October 2017. That can exploit an index on your column.

Second, to make sure you understand your data, try making a detail subquery first, then summarizing it.  For example, first get the details (IF is easier to use than CASE for this):

```
           SELECT Survey_Response_Created_Date,
                  NPS_Deployment_Type,
                  IF(NPSRating BETWEEN 0 AND 10, 1,0) AS total,
                  IF(NPSRating BETWEEN 9 AND 10, 1,0) AS positive,
                  IF(NPSRating BETWEEN 0 AND  6, 1,0) AS negative
             FROM table
```

Then summarize them in an outer query

```
  SELECT (100 * SUM(positive) - SUM(negative))/SUM(total) AS nps,
         SUM(total) AS responses,
         LAST_DAY(Survey_Response_Created_Date) month_ending,
         NPS_Deployment_Type
    FROM (
           SELECT Survey_Response_Created_Date,
                  NPS_Deployment_Type,
                  IF(NPSRating BETWEEN 0 AND 10, 1,0) AS total,
                  IF(NPSRating BETWEEN 9 AND 10, 1,0) AS positive,
                  IF(NPSRating BETWEEN 0 AND  6, 1,0) AS negative
             FROM table
         ) detail
   WHERE Survey_Response_Created_Date >= '2017-10-01'
     AND Survey_Response_Created_Date <  '2017-11-01'
   GROUP BY LAST_DAY(Survey_Response_Created_Date, NPS_Deployment_Type
```

This has the advantage that it's easy to verify your individual survey responses before you try to aggregate them.

Comment: NPS? Really?  It's so 2003. Just sayin.